# LiDAR scanline timestamp information

Tags: timestamp, lidar

I'm working on LiDAR vehicle detection project where we want to obtain the timestamp information for each LiDAR scanline. The PCL HDL Grabber Library provides a single timestamp for each sweepscan (which is a 100 millisecond time span), but I will need accurate timestamp of each lidar firing scanline within each sweepscan.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Kun

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: This is what I have tried: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/hdl_grabber.php

Comment: PCL grabber only gives a single timestamp for each sweep scan, but I need a timestamp for each laser point. What I already found is VeloView can provide these attributes, but I wonder how to do this in PCL?